# как изображение из папки res/drawable превратить в bitmap?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-imageview, android-resources

Работаю в Android Studio на Java. Загрузил несколько картинок в `drawable`и хочу их установить в `Gridview`, но размер изображений большой. Функция которая меняет размер у меня есть

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 150, 150, true));
```

Но ей нужно передать `bitmap` для конвертации. Как из `R.drawable.picture` сделать `bitmap`?

Comment: Может нужно не изменять размер большого изображения, а сделать нормальную поддержку экранов разного размера. Или по какой причине нужно использовать изображения с размером, который приходится конвертировать, чтобы отобразить, вместо того, чтобы сразу использовать изображение подходящего размера?

Comment: вопрос из разряда "погугли за меня, мне лень"

Comment: Да нет, совсем не так. Я гуглил, но просто не разобрался... Поэтому попросил помочь. Я знал, что это не сложный вопрос, но покапался в гугле и не понял как правильно это сделать... Вот и все

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Идём в [гугл](https://www.google.ru/).
2. Вбиваем туда запрос:

> [drawable to bitmap android](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=drawable%20to%20bitmap%20android)

3. Идём по первой ссылке: [How to convert a Drawable to a Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3035692/3212712)
4. Читаем там первый [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3035869/3212712):

   ```
   Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                      R.drawable.picture);
   ```
5. Удивляемся полезности и эффективности задавания своих вопросов бездушной машине.

Comment: Точно)) Спасибо))